# Jquery Select2 not working good for dynamic field

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am creating a dynamic field to which I apply select2 as follows:

```
$('#form-addSubject').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'select', function () {
            currentex = parseInt($("#countE").val(), 10);
            currentQ = parseInt($("#countQE" + currentex).val(), 10) + 1;

            $(this).select2({
                placeholder: "Ex: Lycée, Moyen, Supérieur,...",
                id: function(object) {
                      return object.text;
                },
                /*initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                    callback(levels);
                },*/
                ajax: {
                    url: '/subjects/tags/',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            name_startsWith: params.term,
                            page: params.page
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, params) {
                    // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                      // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                      // scrolling can be used
                      params.page = params.page || 1;
                        return {
                                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        text: item.name,
                                        id: item.pk
                                    };
                                })
                            };
                    },
                    cache: true
                  },
                  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
                  minimumInputLength: 0,
                  minimumResultsForSearch: -1
                });
        });
```

Where #form-addSubject is a static element. The autocomplete part works fine as can be seen in the picture bellow.

[image]

However, I am not able to select any element nor to write on the input field.

Comment: There is some issues when id callback function and ajax are used together. You can find it hee https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/852

Comment: The problem is that it works when the element is static, it just does not when the element is added dynamically.